# XTIFY failed on find provider packagename.XTFY_PROVIDER

Tags: cloud, provider, xtify

I'm following the instructions in http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Google+Cloud+Messaging to implement the push messages for android throught Xtify, and executing my app I get this error:

failed on find provider info com.example.gcmessaging.XTFY_PROVIDER

In the manifest I have on the receiver tag:

....
    android:name="com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider"
    android:authorities="com.example.gcmessaging.XTIFY_PROVIDER"
 android:exported="false"

Can you help me where am I wrong? I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't add the correct package name, you will find it defined in the top of your AndroidManifest.xml File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.site.yourapp" ...>
```

then add the package name to the provider node:

```
<provider
  android:name="com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider"
  android:authorities="com.site.yourapp.XTIFY_PROVIDER"
  android:exported="false" />
```

If it didn't workout for you, let me know.